# password_verify in php issue with logging in

Tags: php, passwords

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $Password = $_POST['passwords'];
    $check_database_query = "SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE   Student_email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $check_database_query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        if ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $passhash = (password_verify($Password, $data['password']));
            if ($passhash == false) {
                $msg = "invalid username or password";
            } else {

                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                header('Location:index.php');
            }
        }
    } else {
        $msg2 = "error";
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-signin" method ="POST"> 
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Login First</h2> 
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"> 
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</form>
```

This wont let me login. Is it because i am comparing the hashed password with the hash or..? sorry about the indentation.

Comment: How are you saving the passwords in the database? In clear text or as a hash?

Comment: they are as a hash using password_hash

Comment: `$Password = $_POST['passwords'];` <<<----- Typo

Comment: yeh i have sorted that and this still wont let me login

Comment: what does `var_dump($data['password']);` yield? Also make sure the field storing the password hash is at least `varchar(60)`

Comment: it outputs string(60) followed by the hashed password

Comment: yes it is more than 60

Comment: By the way, I just noticed you are not using prepared statements. You are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should definitely look that up.